# How to Ensure the apps info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bundle

The app will not run on the simulator or the device but the trouble started when i went to get it on device. Running the latest and greatest Xcode and macOS. Any suggestions are most welcome.

[image: the challenge]

[image]

I suspect this issue is related to the unit testing targets but there is also odd behaviour in the "Signing and Capabilities", when i type in the bundle identifier "com.sw.fw" and hit enter the text in the the textfield vanishes and the "Signing (Release)" duplication appears below with that bundle id. I also created a fresh mobile provisioning profile with the appropriate bundle id `com.sw.fw`

I also know that Xcode is doing something with the bundle id that i'm giving it because it appears on the `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` page of `developer.apple.com` as can be seen here.

[image: developer.apple.com]

Here's the target signing after hitting enter.

[image: Target Signing]

Here's the "Build Settings" for the target

[image: build settings for target]

Here's my info.plist it is the same as an app i have running on device.

[image: info.plist]

Here's a unit test signing

[image: test signing]

Here's the "Build Settings" for a unit test target

[image: test build settings]

App Targets "General" pane doesn't let me type anything in the Bundle Identifier Field. You can see it reads `<Multiple Values>`.

[image]

Comment: "in the "Signing and Capabilities", when i type in the bundle identifier "com.sw.fw"" Well don't do that. You should not be messing with the bundle identifier in any of the places you showed. It comes from the app target's _General_ pane.

Comment: so there is trouble there actually. observe the last image added as an edit. i cannot type anything in there.

Comment: i just tried removing the bundle ids in the Build Settings of each target and adding it only to the General pane of the app target. not yet successful.

Comment: I didn't say remove it. I said you shouldn't have messed with this build setting at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check your Product Bundle Identifier from Build Settings, they might have different values for different builds. Changing the bundle identifier to be the same should solve this issue. In your case removing the 'Any SDK' under debug.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Arun! This was the solution.

Comment: Could be useful a more descriptive image than that

Answer (score 3):

Target > Build Settings > Info plist file

Check Info.plist file path

[image]

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same error and I figured out that I have missed to add or somehow removed `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from my project while I am using firebase in my application. You might be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your `.xcodeproj` container was messed up.

Some options:

- Make sure all targets (including tests and extensions) have the product bundle identifier set in their `Info.plist` files.
- Try to set the product bundle identifier only in the target's `Signing and Capabilities` field instead of manually editing it in different places. Otherwise you risk introducing inconsistencies.
- If you want to dig into `project.pbxpro` you could search for the `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` key and manually check the entries. Compare with a fresh Xcode project on where/how you expect to find the key.
- You can go by elimination and remove targets / custom configurations from the original project until it installs successfully.
- Create a fresh Xcode project and move your code over.

Answer (score 0):

Target > Build Settings > Packaging

In "Info.plist File" add "Target_Name/Info.plist"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the message was not corresponding precisely to the problem.
First, my Launch Screen in the General settings of the target was not good.
In second, I checked my Splashscreen.png that was missing, and I removed it. Then it worked perfectly.
I advice to check if there is an element missing in the ressource etc...